# Google App Engine managed security only works for 'www' alias

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Google is now offering, [in beta](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), a [managed security service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rW8z.jpg) for automated deployment of SSL certificates to GAE apps, which are currently signed by Let's Encrypt. The managed security service is a really good idea, particularly for Windows users, who cannot easily generate SSL certificates through the Let's Encrypt service.

I currently have one custom domain mapping to my GAE app plus its www alias (which means that both 'customdomain.com' and 'www.customdomain.com' map to my app). Also, I have enabled managed security for both of them.

Unfortunately, an HTTPS connection is enforced only if one accesses my app using the www alias (www.customdomain.com). If one does not determine a subdomain (customdomain.com), the connection served is insecure. Of course, one can enforce an HTTPS connection (by adding 'https://' before 'customdomain.com').

Why is that happening? Is that a service bug?

Comment: It is unfortunate that no one could help with this issue, so here is what I did to at least get around it.

I redirected every connection to 'customdomain.com' to one of its subdomains, which I chose to be my landing page. So, if someone tries to reach 'customdomain.com', which would be done through an insecure connection, one is redirected to 'subdomain.customdomain.com', which is secure because the URL contains an alias.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention on the original question that my GAE app is a Python app running on the Standard Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 2017, Google Cloud Platform has introduced **Managed SSL** which should implement SSL to your custom domain by default.

Below is an extract from [this instructional post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html):

> Now, when you build apps on App Engine, SSL is on by default —  you no
>   longer need to worry about it or spend time managing it. We’ve made
>   using HTTPS simple: map a domain to your app, prove ownership, and App
>   Engine automatically provisions an SSL certificate and renews it
>   whenever necessary, at no additional cost. Purchasing and generating
>   certificates, dealing with and securing keys, managing your SSL cipher
>   suites and worrying about renewal dates —  those are all a thing of
>   the past.

You can specify the paths that you wish to be secured inside the `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

Comment: I had already tried to use the 'secure' option for url handlers before, but it didn't work as expected for my application back then. Today, after updating my app.yaml file with more handlers (as described here: https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098) to deal with another issue, I decided to add the 'secure' option to all of them and, finally, my GAE app is now being served through HTTPS by default, without any kind of trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding secure property really helped me! I was pulling my hair since 2 days nowhere in documentation for custom domain on GCP App engine this was stated :/